# Prolog OR operator (;) returns error

Tags: prolog

I'm new to Prolog and I'm trying to make the code below succeed when the first two and one of the bottom two succeeds.

However, so far i get the following error: ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated

What am i doing wrong?

```
same(Object,Attribute,Value,CF) :-
 trace_value(Object,Attribute),!,
 fact(Object,Attribute,Value,CF),!,
 CF > 0.2.    

add(dentist,model,'Acute Lateral Abscess',
  cf(0.6,[CF1,CF2,CF3,CF4])) :-
     same(dentist,pocketing_depth,c,CF1),
     same(dentist,miscellaneous_sinus,present,CF2),
     (   same(dentist,pain_character5,yes,CF3)
     ;   same(dentist,pain_character3,yes,CF4)
     ).
```

Example:
I ask the user the following:

```
userprompt(dentist,tooth_recent_fillings) :-
    nl,
    write('Is there evidence of recent fillings?'),
    nl.
```

Then run this model:

```
add(dentist,model,'Pulpitis',
 cf(0.3,[CF1])):-
   same(dentist,tooth_recent_fillings,yes,CF1).
```

I run it with: consultation(dentist,model).

And then it gives me an outcome that the patient suffers of pulpitis.

Comment: What do you mean by `CF7` etc. I am new to dental diagnosis (what a horrifying subject!), but I suspect that this should be some probability in stead. Like 0.4.

Comment: yes that's right, that's what i mean. It's my certainty factor, i fill it in with my input

Comment: Do you think you could explain in more detail what you’re trying to do and provide a definition of `same` that would allow us to query it?

Comment: I'm trying to match a diagnosis with symptoms.

The same method checks if the user input on a particular question is the same as in the code for that diagnosis.

Comment: Okay.  It would help if you gave a definition of `same` that I could actually query and an example of a query and what the output should be.  Right now, I just get an error message that says `trace_value` is not defined (on SWI Prolog).

Comment: I tried to make it a little bit more clear above.

Comment: That latest version does compile.  I still can’t actually run it because most of the definition of `same` is missing.  But now, you’re using `;` in a list of clauses, rather than a list of facts.

Comment: You should look at the line of code that your error message is pertaining to. It means that you have an expression that requires a particular variable to be instantiated, but at the time of execution, it's not. For example, `CF > 0.2` requires that `CF` have a value when executed. But if it doesn't, you will get that error.

Comment: @user3106974 If you mean `cf(0.6,[...])`, then no, you do not fill it in your input. The `add` predicate only see the `cf/2` term partially instanciated in the input. I assume `cf` unifies all the variables with the value, so you need to actually *call* the term in-order to instanciate all variables, which is not currently done (arguments are not evaluated in a functional style, but unified). You'll have to take, for example, a CF argument, and before calling `same`, you explicitely call `cf(CF,[...])`.